# Programmatically play last Track listened to in SoundCloud

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, soundcloud, headset

I'm the developer of [Bluetooth Connect & Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player) and I've been asked to support SoundCloud.   Most apps I support respond to Headset Controls (Play/Pause etc..), but SoundCloud does not.   I see that there are special Intent Actions supported like toggleplayback, but if SoundCloud is stricken from memory, it doesn't remember the last track to play.  So I can start SoundCloud, but that Action doesn't cause any action unless SoundCloud remembers what to play.   Is there a trick I'm missing, or a way to supply a "continue where left off" element?

Also, it would be more consistent, for me, if you supported HeadSet controls, just a suggestion :)

..>Carl

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to contact SoundCloud developers and ask them to support Headset Controls. Anything else would be a hack.

Comment: Thanks.  Their site says they give technical support here.  So hoping they see this